# How to escape the skulls (mist unit)

Tags: metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain

I'm spending my first days with the **Metal Gear Solid V : Phantom Pain** and, although I escaped alive from them, I'm still wondering if there is a smart way to escape from the **mist unit (skulls**) in the first encounters with them.

I have just run away and eventually it worked out.

Comment: Do you mean the encounter when you rescue Miller?

Comment: Yes, and afterwards when recovering the honey bee. I haven't said more detealis for avoiding spoilers.

Comment: I see. Well, in the first encounter, it's possible to sneak past them, it just takes a while. For the second one - I don't really know of a smart way. When the encounter started, I turned around and there was a car. I used that for my escape.

Comment: In the second encounter, Ocelot suggests to use the Honey Bee but I didn't find it useful at all. Actually I wasn't sure where to aim.

Comment: Hell i just blew through them on D-Horse shooting my rifle at them and swearing to myself both times so far

Comment: The Honey Bee removes 50% of the health of a Skull, it is quite efficient.

Comment: ^ what this guy said - I was bricking it but that thing tore them a new one, 2 were close together and both got battered.

Answer (score 2):

The Skulls can be avoided in their first appearance (Resucing Miller / Phantom Limbs) with a little bit of patience.

First, use your IntScan to mark all 4 Skulls -- two at the top of the bridge, and 2 along the slope to the left of it.

Now, you wait. The skulls will slowly shamble forwards, with the left skulls going down the slope, and the right skulls approaching and then beginning to go down the slope on the far side of the bridge. Your approach should be straight across. Once the right-pair has started down the slope, make your move. You have a rather narrow window where the Right skulls are far enough down the slope to break line of sight before they come back up the hill and camp the edge of the bridge.

Once you're a good 100m on the far side of the skulls, feel free to whistle up D-Horse, fling Miller over his back, and casually ride the rest of the way to the extraction site.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, change the helicopter's landing zone. If you take out the radar dish, you can have your chopper land right outside the prison. (Just make sure the guards are unavailable/incapacitated!)

Comment: For me, the ones to the right slowly crossed the bridge.  I had to go up the slope.

Comment: Both left and right skulls will slowly shamble towards your position, even if they don't know you're there (game logic), so if you stand on the right side of the bridge, the skulls across the bridge will shamble down the right slope, if you stand across the bridge, they will cross the bridge etc.

Comment: @CeilingGecko Good to know! In that case, stand to the right of the bridge.

Comment: Moving the landing zone skips the entire thing. Definitely recommended.

Comment: I must say, I found their first appearance incredibly frustrating. As someone who has never played MGS before perhaps I don't understand their significance, but damn, what a nice way to frustrate someone by implying that you have to run past them on your horse and somehow escape them.

Answer (score 2):

#### First encounter (Extraction):

I marked the Skulls, headed down the hill towards the valley/bridge, went under the bridge (left to right), and then waited until the two Skulls on the bridge had crossed half way.

After that, I happily galloped off to the LZ.

#### Second Encounter (Honey):

After the cutscene, circled the compound counter-clockwise at the edge until I came to the area you can climb up. Climbed up, the end of the mist was extremely close. Didn't encounter any Skulls closer than 20m.

Answer (score 1):

Skulls react to noise just like any other enemy. I went up top so that I was on the opposite end of the bridge from them and starting creeping forward. I then threw some empty magazines to their left (my right... since that was the side of the bridge they favored) so that they'd turn away. They seem to have terrible sight lines and I crouch-walked right past them. No waiting required.

Answer (score -2):

With the Skulls’ first encounter, my luck (Welp technically it was my fault) had it so that the two on the bridge split up, one went down the right slope whilst the other went on the bridge. Luckily for me, I had been waiting on the far side of the bridge (and they have terrible sight lines) so once the two who go down the left slope had gone under the bridge, I managed to sprint past all of them without being noticed. Took me a few tries though gotta admit.

Answer (score -4):

Metal Gear Solid 5 The Phantom Pain Walkthrough Part 2 Phantom Limbs GeForce GTX 960

Comment: You might want to summarise some of the information in here, in case (for whatever reason) the video becomes unavailable. Or even, is unavailable in / on other countries / platforms. Also, possibly, editing the URL to start at roughly 22 minutes.